# Change .NET Development Utility (DNU) version in Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dnx, coreclr, dnu

how I could changing version of DNU utility used by Visual Studio Code?

I have switched CoreCLR version to 1.0.0-beta5 (using DNVM)

When I'm typed "dnu" in command line, there are used correct version (CoreCLR-x64-1.0.0-beta5-12103)

When I run "dnu restore" task from Visual Studio Code, are used different version - "Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231"

Version of VS Code - 0.10.5

Thanks, Petr

Answer (score 1):

Put a `gloabl.json` file inside the root of your solution (or any sub directory relative to your `project.json` file) and define the runtime version you want to use like [this](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/ModernShopping/blob/8b980cf211d803161a06e8f2043acf16d37010b8/Auth/global.json).

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar type of issues but it is resolved after changing the 
default dnx version.

I was not sure about command to change the defalt dnx so I re-installed x86 and I noticed that the dnx version which is installed at last become the default dnx version.
To reinstall it use following command

```
dnvm install 1.0.0.-rc1-update1 -arch x86
```

Before installation of x86
[image]

after installing x86
[image]

if this is not you case or it does not resolve your issue. you can remove all your existing dnx version and reinstall the dnx for version "1.0.0.-rc1-update1" or latest available version.

**Added**

to change the DNX runtime Version use the following command

```
dnvm use <DNX Version> -r <Runtime> -arch <Architecture>
```

e.g. `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr -arch x64`

and to see the current version use

```
dnx --version
```

[image]
But this is not persistent it will apply to the current session only if you want to make your changes persistent then use the below command.

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr -arch x64 -p
```